# Is there anyway to copy the data from a single column in a Python pandas dataframe into a string or list for further processing?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I am trying to iterate over a Python pandas created dataframe column by column. While it is easy to get Python to print out a whole column, I simply cannot work out how to turn this column of data into a list or string so I can actually use the data it contains (in this case, concatenating the data and copying it into a FASTA file). My code is below. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sys
import string
import shlex
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
SNP_df = pd.read_csv('SNPs.txt',sep='\t',index_col = None ,header = None, nrows = 101) 

output = open('100 SNPs.fa','a')

i=1
for i in SNP_df[i]:
    data = SNP_df[i]
    data = shlex.shlex(data, posix = True)
    data.whitespace += "\n"
    data.whitespace_split = True
    data = list(data)
    for j in data:
        if j == 0:
            output.write(("\n>%s\n")%(str(data(j))))
        else:
            output.write(data(j))
```

Here are the first few lines of my data file:
POSITION    REF AR_DM1005   AR_DM1015   AR_DM1050   AR_DM1056   AR_DM1088   AR_KB635    AR_KB652    AR_KB754    AR_KB819    AR_KB820    AR_KB827    AR_KB945    AR_MSH126   AR_MSH51    PP_BdA1134-13   PP_BdA1137-10   PP_DM1038   PP_DM1049   PP_DM1054   PP_DM1065   PP_DM1081   PP_DM1084   PP_JR83 ST_JR138    ST_JR158    ST_JR209    ST_JR72 ST_JR84 ST_JR91 ST_MSH177   ST_MSH217   CH_JR198    CH_JR20 CH_JR272    CH_JR356    CH_JR377    CH_KB888    CH_MSH202   TL_MA1959   TL_MSH130   TL_SCI12-2  TL_SPE123_2-3   TL_SPE123_5-1   TL_SPE123_6-3   TL_SPE123_7-1   TL_SPE123_8-1   CU_SPE123_1-2   CU_SPE123_4-1   Dmir_SP138
55  C   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   C
380 G   G   A   A   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   A   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G
391 A   A   G   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
402 G   A   A   A   A   G   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   G   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   G   A   A   A   G   A   A   A   A   G   A   A   A   A   G
422 A   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   A   A   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   A   C   C   C   A   C   C   C   C   A   C   C   C   C   A
564 G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   A   A   G   G   G   G   G   G   A   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G

Comment: Could you give a few -- 3, say -- example lines from `SNPs.txt`?  I suspect `shlex` isn't needed here at all.

Answer (score 0):

just use numpy! you can convert a Series (1 column DataFrame) into a 1D numpy array easily!

```
import numpy as np
for i in SNP_df:
    data = SNP_df[i]
    data = np.array(data)
    for j in data:
        if j == 0:
            output.write(("\n>%s\n")%(str(data(j))))
        else:
            output.write(data(j))
```

Comment: Sure. Here is a truncated version of the first 3 lines:
POSITION REF AR_DM1005 AR_DM1015 AR_DM1050 AR_DM1056 AR_DM1088 AR_KB635 AR_KB652 AR_KB754 AR_KB819 AR_KB820 AR_KB827 AR_KB945
55 C T T T T T T T T T T T T
380 G G A A G G G G G G G G G

Comment: I keep getting this error message: 'no item names REF'. REF is the first object in the first cell of the second column of data (I am excluding the second column of data, as this contains a list of number that I do not intend to use). Any suggestions?

Comment: I am confused as to what you mean by that? is ref supposed to be a column and it's being read in a cell?

Comment: REF is the name of the first cell in the first column that I am trying to parse; ie:
REF
C
G
A
G...

Comment: there was actually a typo in my function, but I fixed it! try it now

Answer (score 0):

Using your example data. Note that due to copy&paste the tabs becaming white space (so using sep='\s+', iso '\t') and i have set the first row of the data as the column names (not using header=None). Concatenating one column to a string can be done using join.

```
In [20]: from StringIO import StringIO

In [21]: data = """\
   ....: POSITION REF AR_DM1005 AR_DM1015 AR_DM1050 AR_DM1056 AR_DM1088 AR_KB635 AR_KB652 AR_KB754 AR_KB819 AR_KB820 AR_KB827 AR_KB945 AR_MSH126 AR_MSH51 PP_BdA1134-13 PP_BdA1137-10 PP_DM1038 PP_DM1049 PP_DM1054 PP_DM1065 PP_DM1081 PP_DM1084 PP_JR83 ST_JR138 ST_JR158 ST_JR209 ST_JR72 ST_JR84 ST_JR91 ST_MSH177 ST_MSH217 CH_JR198 CH_JR20 CH_JR272 CH_JR356 CH_JR377 CH_KB888 CH_MSH202 TL_MA1959 TL_MSH130 TL_SCI12-2 TL_SPE123_2-3 TL_SPE123_5-1 TL_SPE123_6-3 TL_SPE123_7-1 TL_SPE123_8-1 CU_SPE123_1-2 CU_SPE123_4-1 Dmir_SP138
   ....: 55 C T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T C
   ....: 380 G G A A G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G A G G G G G G G G G
   ....: 391 A A G A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
   ....: 402 G A A A A G A A A A A A A A A G A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A G A A A G A A A A G A A A A G
   ....: 422 A C C C C C C C C C C C C C C A A C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C A C C C A C C C C A C C C C A
   ....: 564 G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G A A G G G G G G A G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G
   ....: """

In [22]: import pandas as pd

In [23]: SNP_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+', index_col=None, nrows=101)

In [24]: SNP_df['AR_DM1005']
Out[24]:
0    T
1    G
2    A
3    A
4    C
5    G
Name: AR_DM1005, dtype: object

In [25]: ''.join(SNP_df['AR_DM1005'])
Out[25]: 'TGAACG'
```